# Simple form not passing all variables?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have a simple form that uses ajax to post the data to a php script that sends email. Its worked fine with just name field, but when i am f_name and l_name it doesnt seem to pass them?

The html is

```
    body { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#444; }

input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:8px;
    margin:2px 0;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#8f8f8f;
    width:250px;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 8px #e5e8e7;
}
input[type=submit] {
    border:none;
    padding:8px 25px;
    margin:2px 0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    background:#0d7963;
    border-radius:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    opacity:0.9;
}
</style>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myform').on('submit',function(){

        // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
        $('.output_message').text('Processing...'); 

        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            method: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                if (result == 'success'){
                    $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');  
                } else {
                    $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
                }
            }
        });

        // Prevents default submission of the form after clicking on the submit button. 
        return false;   
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" class="myform" action="process-form3.php">
    <input type="text" name="f_name" placeholder="Your first Name" required><br>
    <input type="text" name="l_name" placeholder="Your last Name" required><br>

    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required><br>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send"> <span class="output_message"></span>
</form>
```

the php file is :

```
    <?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['f_name'],$_REQUEST['email'])) {

    $f_name = $_REQUEST['f_name'];
    $l_name = $_REQUEST['l_name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

$new_message = $message+f_name+l_name;


    // Set your email address where you want to receive emails. 
    $to = 'billycov@icloud.com';

    $subject = 'Contact Request From Website';
    $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email."> \r\n";

    $send_email = mail($to,$subject,$new_message,$headers);

    echo ($send_email) ? 'success' : 'error';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some issues I've found:

1. You're concatening PHP strings like JavaScript here:

   ```
   $new_message = $message+f_name+l_name;
   ```

   Just replace with:

   ```
   $new_message = $message . $f_name . $l_name;
   ```
2. Apparently, `$name` is not defined here:

   ```
   $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email."> \r\n";
   ```

I think that's it!

Answer (score 0):

problem here:

```
$headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email."> \r\n";
```

you should define `$name` or use one of `$f_name` or `$l_name`

Comment: Thanks, i already did that but must have changed it back my accident, working fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

wrong concatenating in this line:

```
$new_message = $message+f_name+l_name;
```

it should be look like this:

```
$new_message = $message.$f_name.$l_name;
```

and also you need to replace $name with $f_name in this line:

```
$headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email."> \r\n";
```

there you go ;)